# Есть ли возможность отправить пакет с сервера, если сервер и клиент подключены к одному порту, но ip клиента не известен?

Tags: java, сервер, udp, client

Есть приложение написанное на Java, которое может работать как в режиме сервера, так и в режиме клиента по протоколу UDP(реализовано через DatagramSocket). И клиент, и сервер могут отправлять пакет, единственное различие между ними - если приложение запущено в режиме сервера, то оно создается на конкретном ip и имеет конкретный порт, в случае если приложение запущено в режиме клиента, то оно при запуске имеет лишь ip и порт сервера, которому необходимо отправлять пакет. Вопрос заключается в следующем: есть ли возможность отправить пакет с сервера клиенту, если у сервера есть только общий порт с клиентом, при условии, что socket клиента создан с таким же портом, что и сервер?

**P.S.** Я понимаю, что можно отправить тестовый пакет с клиента на сервер и оттуда получить ip клиента, но этот вариант мне не подходит, так как это UDP и я не могу быть уверен, что сервер получит этот пакет.

**P.S.S.** Изначально задать какой-то конкретный ip клиенту не совсем то, что мне нужно, из-за чего у меня и возник вопрос, есть ли возможность отправить пакет, зная лишь порт.

Comment: Подсеть общая, внутри NAT? Шлите на broadcast)

Comment: Конечно нету, порт - просто число в пакете. Допустим, в сети висят 3 таких клиента. как их различить-то?

Comment: Осознал, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если что-то не известно - это можно узнать. Запусти пакет на stun сервер с этого же сокета и он выдаст адрес и порт клиента - на них можно слать пакеты извне и они дойдут. Вопрос только в сигнальном сервере, который расскажет серверу где клиент, а клиенту где сервер.

Для работы внутри сети принято использовать мультикаст.